# FFmpeg tool graph2dot doesn't recognize some filters

Tags: ffmpeg

I have `graph2dot` FFmpeg utility for converting *filtergraph descriptions* to the textual representations in the *dot language* for their subsequent *visualisation*.

(Thanks to [Mulvya](https://video.stackexchange.com/users/1871/mulvya) who uploaded it in [this answer](https://video.stackexchange.com/a/21041/18155)).

It works fine for me but it doesn't recognize some filters, e. g. `mpdecimate` and `delogo`:

> No such filter: 'mpdecimate'
>   No such filter: 'delogo'

Is there some way (e. g. a newer version of this program or its DLL libraries) to fix it?

Comment: My upload was compiled using license LGPL. I need to compile it as GPL to include those filters. I'll do it in a couple of days.

Comment: @Mulvya - If you will have time, please build and upload it. I'll appreciate it.

Comment: In a couple of days or so.

Comment: Updated in original answer.

Comment: @Mulvya - Thank you very much, I tried it an it works! I'm sorry that I have no chance to appreciate your work at least by voting up your answer. If you will put it here as an answer, I will be glad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The older upload did not cover those filters as they require GPL license and the older binary was built with a LGPL configure.

I've uploaded a 64-bit GPL3 Windows binary of graph2dot (with 4 dependencies) to http://www.datafilehost.com/d/6fcd14be

Source is at https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/master/tools/graph2dot.c

License is at https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/master/COPYING.GPLv3